# Disable WLAN as kernel boot option?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, boot, kernel

I have a [CubieTruck Plus (CubieBoard5)](http://cubieboard.org/model/) running Linaro. It has an ethernet port and wifi card. I want to disable unneeded services and reduce power, so I want to stop anything related to wifi and wlan0 early.

The board's `/etc/network/interfaces` does not enable wlan0 or wifi. However, when I inspect `dmesg` output during boot I see the card is enabled (see below).

I checked [kernel boot parameters](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt), but did not see anything related to disabling wifi or wlan0. There is a `rfkill.default_state` which handles airplane mode, but this device does not have such a button (and may not do what I expect).

How can I disable WLAN as a boot time option or a kernel boot parameter?

---

```
cubietruck:~$ dmesg | egrep -i '(wlan|wifi|802)'
[    0.162278] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[    5.128958] [rf_pm]: set ac10032k2 32k out[wifi_pm]: wifi gpio init is OK !!
[    6.789026] [wifi_pm]: set wl_reg_on 1 !
[    6.789260] =========== WLAN placed in POWER ON ========
[    6.913059] bcm_wlan_get_oob_irq enter.
[    6.940204] Broadcom Dongle Host Driver: register interface [wlan0] MAC: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
[    6.940389] [wifi_pm]: set wl_reg_on 0 !
[    6.940400] =========== WLAN placed in RESET ========
[   11.609474] wl_android_wifi_on in 1
[   11.609483] wl_android_wifi_on in 2: g_wifi_on=0
[   11.609492] [wifi_pm]: set wl_reg_on 1 !
[   11.609707] =========== WLAN going back to live  ========
[   11.715036] dhd_bus_devreset: == WLAN ON ==
[   12.140869] wl_android_wifi_on: Success
[   12.142367] wl_cfg80211_attach_post: p2p0 p2p_dev_addr=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
[   16.407047] CFG80211-ERROR) wl_notify_scan_status : scan is not ready 
[   21.372467] CFG80211-ERROR) wl_notify_scan_status : scan is not ready 
[   23.150025] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
```

Comment: Actually your request is ambiguous.  Technically the WiFi services are usually enabled/disable in userspace.  What you posted in the boot log is for the WiFi device driver.  To prevent the kernel from installing the WiFi driver in an ARM system, a modified Device Tree blob would be needed.  But since the Cubie uses an Allwinner SoC, it may be using its own board configuration scheme of *fex* instead of dtb.

Comment: Thanks @sawdust. I'm kind of surprised at how difficult this seems to be. Naively, I thought I would have been able to do it when booting the kernel, similar to turning off IPv6. `lsmod` does not appear to list a driver available to blacklist.

Comment: You're still confusing apples with oranges.  IPv6 is a protocol that is often considered optional.  The WiFi driver would seem to be statically linked into the kernel if it doesn't appear in as a module.  Check the source code of the WiFi driver, to see if it supports *power management*